# Android SQLite - Is it possible to retrive data grouped by week/month?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a SQLite Table as below

```
Column1      :  Detail
2014-10-07   :   5
2014-10-09   :   5
2014-10-14   :   6
2014-10-15   :   6
2014-10-22   :   7
2014-10-23   :   7
```

I want to retrieve detail column values added up Grouped by week (Week can be any - Sunday to sunday or any).

Results should be 10,12,14.  if Friday is end of the week.

Is this possible in SQLite with any query ?

Comment: read this document http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT  sum(detail)'calculatedvalue'  FROM Test group by STRFTIME('%W', date);
```

**Tested on this data**

[image]

**Query Output**

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me what tool you are using to validate this sql? in the screenshot you have provided.